# Understanding origin of back slashes in JSON encoded response

Tags: php

I have a long script which crops an image, saves it to server, inserts the path into SQL, more form fields. I'm having issues with it saving the file paths to SQL. The script is close to 200 lines long and I doubt anyone wants to look through it, so I'm trying to trouble shoot.

The end of the script responds back to the page that contains the form using this:

```
            public function getResult() {
            return !empty($this -> data) ? $this -> dst : $this -> src;
        }

        public function getMsg() {
            return $this -> msg;
        }
    }
$crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file']);
    $response = array(
        'state'  => 200,
        'message' => $crop -> getMsg(),
        'result' => $crop -> getResult()
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

When I look at the response data in Firebug, I am getting this:

```
{"state":200,"message":null,"result":"..\/0images\/listimg\/mod\/20141119183449.jpeg"}
```

Where are the back slashes coming from?

I don't have any backslashes anywhere in my PHP code, which looks like this:

```
<?php
require('../dbcon2.php');
//Connection 1
try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO listings (title, address, lot_size, zoning, build_size, sale_price, lease_price, comment, transaction, date_added) VALUES (:title, :address, :lot_size, :zoning, :build_size, :sale_price, :lease_price, :comment, :transaction, now())");
          $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']); 
          $stmt->bindParam(':address', $_POST['address']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':lot_size', $_POST['lot_size']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':zoning', $_POST['zoning']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':build_size', $_POST['build_size']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':sale_price', $_POST['sale_price']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':lease_price', $_POST['lease_price']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':comment', $_POST['comment']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':transaction', $_POST['transaction']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $id = $conn->lastInsertId();
//Create class
    class CropAvatar {
        private $src;
        private $data;
        private $file;
        private $dst;
        private $type;
        private $extension;
        private $srcDir = '../0images/listimg/orig';
        private $dstDir = '../0images/listimg/mod';
        private $msg;

function __construct($src, $data, $file, $id, $ad_link, $listing_img) {
    $this -> setSrc($src);
    $this -> setData($data);
    $this -> setFile($file);
    $this -> setId($id);
    $this -> setAd_link($ad_link);
    $this -> setListing_img($listing_img);
    $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data, $this -> id, $this -> ad_link, $this -> listing_img);
}
        private $id;
        public function setId($id) {
                 $this->id = $id;
}
            private $ad_link;
        public function setAd_link($ad_link) {
                 $this->ad_link = $ad_link;
}
            private $listing_img;
        public function setListing_img($listing_img) {
                 $this->listing_img = $listing_img;
}
        private function setSrc($src) {
            if (!empty($src)) {
                $type = exif_imagetype($src);
                if ($type) {
                    $this -> src = $src;
                    $this -> type = $type;
                    $this -> extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                    $this -> setDst();
                }
            }
        }
        private function setData($data) {
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $this -> data = json_decode(stripslashes($data));
            }
        }
        private function setFile($file) {
            $errorCode = $file['error'];
            if ($errorCode === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $type = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);
                if ($type) {
                    $dir = $this -> srcDir;
                    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                        mkdir($dir, 0777);
                    }
                    $currdate=date('YmdHis');
                    $extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                    $src = $dir . '/' . $currdate . $extension;
                    if ($type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
                        if (file_exists($src)) {
                            unlink($src);
                        }
                        $result = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $src);
                        $listing_img="http://www.website.com/0images/listimg/mod/" . $currdate . $extension;
 //Process file upload 
                        $allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
                            $tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                        $extensionf = end($tempf);
                        if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
                        && ($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] <2000000000)
                        && in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) 
                        {
                            $flyername=$_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
                            if ($_FILES["flyer"]["error"] > 0) 
                            {
                            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["flyer"]["error"] . "<br>";
                            }   
                                else 
                                {
                                    if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) 
                                    {
                                     unlink("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                                    }

                                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"],"../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                                        $ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
                        //Error handling
                            require('../dbcon2.php');
                            try {
                                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                $sql="UPDATE listings SET ad_link='$this->ad_link', listing_img='$this->listing_img' WHERE id='$this->id'";
                                $conn->exec($sql);
                                }
                            catch(PDOException $e)
                                {
                                echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                                }
                            $conn = null;
                                           }}
                //Error handling
                        if ($result) {
                            $this -> src = $src;
                            $this -> type = $type;
                            $this -> extension = $extension;
                            $this -> setDst();
                        } else {
                             $this -> msg = 'Failed to save file';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this -> msg = 'Please upload image with the following types: JPG, PNG, GIF';
                    }
                } else {
                    $this -> msg = 'Please upload image file';
                }
            } else {
                $this -> msg = $this -> codeToMessage($errorCode);
            }
        }

        private function setDst() {
            $dir = $this -> dstDir;

            if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                mkdir($dir, 0777);
            }

            $this -> dst = $dir . '/' . date('YmdHis') . $this -> extension;
        }

        private function crop($src, $dst, $data) {
            if (!empty($src) && !empty($dst) && !empty($data)) {
                switch ($this -> type) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                        break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                        break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                        break;
                }

                if (!$src_img) {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to read the image file";
                    return;
                }

                $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 220);
                $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $data -> x, $data -> y, 220, 220, $data -> width, $data -> height);

                if ($result) {
                    switch ($this -> type) {
                        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                            $result = imagegif($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;

                        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                            $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;

                        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                            $result = imagepng($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;
                    }

                    if (!$result) {
                        $this -> msg = "Failed to save the cropped image file";
                    }
                } else {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to crop the image file";
                }

                imagedestroy($src_img);
                imagedestroy($dst_img);
            }
        }
        private function codeToMessage($code) {
            switch ($code) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                    $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                    $message = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                    $message = 'No file was uploaded';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                    $message = 'Missing a temporary folder';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                    $message = 'Failed to write file to disk';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                    $message = 'File upload stopped by extension';
                    break;

                default:
                    $message = 'Unknown upload error';
            }

            return $message;
        }

        public function getResult() {
            return !empty($this -> data) ? $this -> dst : $this -> src;
        }

        public function getMsg() {
            return $this -> msg;
        }
    }
$crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file']);
    $response = array(
        'state'  => 200,
        'message' => $crop -> getMsg(),
        'result' => $crop -> getResult()
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
        }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: and the back slashes just vanashed from by question

Comment: Are you sure it's json doing it? For all your know your `getResult()` method is doing it. JSON would have no reason to escape the slashes in the strings. They're not metacharacters.

Comment: @MarcB ok, would pdo do this?

Comment: no. pdo doesn't change data either.

Comment: I'm gonna post the code if you feel like taking a look, but don't blame you if you don't

Comment: don't know how it'd help. just backtrack through your object and figure out where the escaping's being introduced. heck, go look at the raw database record. see if they're in the DB to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's `json_encode` function is escaping the slashes (see http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php for the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` constant you can use if using a recent enough version of PHP).

It is perfectly valid JSON to escape slash with a backslash (see the definition of a **string** on http://json.org/), so your decoder should handle it anyway.

The reason to escape a slash is to avoid the character sequence `</script>` which must never appear in the string representation of a JSON object, so many JSON encoders only encode `/` when the previous character is `<` (but not PHP's :)).